# Link ajax pagination

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a problem with my pagination in ajax, I've tried to create a script with jQuery to generate pagination using Wordpress. My script is this :

```
<script>
jQuery(document).on('click', '.page a', function(e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    open_sidebar();
    scrollToAnchor('ajax_posts_home');
    jQuery('.home_load_posts').show(2000);
    jQuery('.home_load_posts').animate({
        opacity: 0.85
    }, 1000);

    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');  

    jQuery('#home_content_posts').load(link+' #home_content_posts');
}); 
</script>

<?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
```

This works perfectly and doesn't give me any problem. The real problem is when I go and click on another link on the website. When I do this the script loads the content of that link and i don´t understand why this happened, it should only load the pagination links.

If the class is class="page", I don´t understand why the script activates and launches another page with another class

The only problem is that the other links must load as normal without ajax, but for some reason I don´t know, all the links load as ajax when the class name is diferent

The regular link format to load on front of website for pagination is like this :

```
<div class="wp-pagenavi">
    <span class="current">1</span>
    <a href="http://domain.com/page/2/" class="page" title="2">2</a>
    <a href="http://domain.com/page/3/" class="page" title="3">3</a>
    <a href="http://domain.com/page/2/" class="nextpostslink">»</a>
</div>

<div class="clearboth"> </div>
</div>
```

I don't understand why this happend. I understand it must only load the pagination via ajax and no the other links of website

Thanks, Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `a.page` for the jQuery onclick callback. `a.page` means all the `<a>` tags with a class of `.page`. Doing `.page a` means all the `<a>` tags that are a descendant of an element with the class of `.page`.  So to fix your javascript you'd do:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', 'a.page', function(e) {
```

Comment: Yeah man ! , it´s perfect !!! thank´s a lot , great works very fine i use for paginate with ajax results or posts and all day thinking what´s badd , great , thank´s for your help haha :)